# Package is available on packages.ubuntu.com but not in Ubuntu using apt

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04

I want to install the package `libc6-dev-amd64` on Ubuntu 18.04 but `apt` says that there is no such package:

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev-amd64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc6-dev-amd64
```

Also trying with the architecture fails (this should not be required):

```
sudo apt install libc6-dev-amd64:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libc6-dev-amd64:i386
```

When I search for `libc6-dev-amd64` at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ it clearly show that this package is available: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6-dev-amd64&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all.

Why doesn't `apt` know about it?

Comment: It says it's available for the `i386` architecture. Are you on the i386 arch? Which arch are you on? Why do you need to install this instead of [`libc6-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libc6-dev&searchon=names)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable foreign arch - i386:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo apt update
```

#### Then you can start install by:

```
$ sudo apt install libc6-dev-amd64:i386
```

#### or just

```
$ sudo apt install libc6-dev-amd64
```

Because only one package "libc6-dev-amd64:i386".

Comment: Thank you, so this was enabled in the default installation prior to 18.04.